# SOQL child related list from User object

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, soql

I would like to use a SOQL Query to load what is displayed at a user record, what I want to get is the:

1. Permission Set Assignments **Related list records**
2. Public Group Membership **Related list records**
3. Queue Membership **Related list Records**

I am currently able to retrieve the permission set Related list records for a particular user but I am unable to get the public group and the queue membership related list records,

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Id, name, (select PermissionSet.Name, AssigneeId 
FROM PermissionSetAssignments) from user
```

Could you please help me adding the missing part in the query to get the queues and the public groups,

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not get Public group and Queue membership details directly from user object. You need additional query.

```
SELECT Id, GroupId, UserOrGroupId 
FROM GroupMember 
WHERE UserOrGroupId IN (SELECT Id FROM User)
```

Since queue is a public group you don't need additional query to get queue membership. This single query is enough.